# How to remove empty array in filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of object like this

```
let arr = [{
 user: 1,
 details: 'sample' },
{
 user: null,
 details: 'sample' },
{
 user: 3,
 details: 'sample' }];
```

I want to filter out the null user. But when I tried to map the array I get this result.

`[user1, [], user3]`

I want to get rid of the `[]` so I can get the correct data and length. How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: There is no `[]` ?

Comment: Please show us the code

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, the condition inside the filter will check if user inside each item is a truthy value or not. So added advantage is you can remove out users having user as `undefined` or `""` or `null` from the original array

```js
  const users = [
    { user: 1, details: "sample" },
    {user: null, details: "sample"},
    {user: 3, details: "sample"}
  ];

const result = users.filter((item) => item.user);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Note that `{ user: 0, details:"sample" }` will be removed too.

Answer (score 2):

```
const users = 
    [{
      user: 1,
      details: 'sample' },
    {
      user: null,
     details: 'sample' },
    {
     user: 3,
     details: 'sample' 
    }]
```

**Easiest way**:

`const newUsers = users.filter(item => item.user)`

Answer (score 1):

**Below snippets are from [w3docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript.html).**

To remove empty elements from a JavaScript Array, the filter() method can be used, which will return a new array with the elements passing the criteria of the callback function.

The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test. To remove null or undefined values do the following:

```
const array = [0, null, 1, "", 2, undefined, 2, , , , , 4, , 4, , 5, , 6, , , , ];
const arrFiltered = array.filter(el => {
  return el != null && el != '';
});
console.log(arrFiltered);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const data = ["user1", [], "user3"];
 const res = data.filter(
        (item) => item !== Array.isArray(item) && item.length
      );
 console.log(res);
```

First check if your element is an array `Array.isArray(item)` and then check if you array has length, if no it means it is an empty and we can filter it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter like that,

```
  yourArr = yourArr.filter(element => element.user != null);
```

see the attached image it contains the answer

[image: example for using array filter method in javascript]

Comment: How can you achieve the same without a filter?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
var arr = [{ user: 1, details: 'sample' }, { user: null, details: 'sample' }, { user: 3, details: 'sample' }];
var result = arr2.filter(el => el.user !== null);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
var newArray = array.filter(value => Object.keys(value).length !== 0);
```

Comment: Downvoted becuase if you use the `const array = [0, null, 1, "", 2, undefined, 2, , , , , 4, , 4, , 5, , 6, , , , ];` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62977205/446954 above, this function raises a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` exception.